# Max retries exceeded with url Caused by NewConnectionError Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, dns, out-of-memory, urllib3

I am requesting an API using the python requests library:

My python script is run once a day by the scheduler, Once the python script gets run, I am getting this error and the PID of the python script is getting killed showing OOM.
I am not getting whether it's a DNS issue or an OOM (Out of memory) issue as the process is getting killed.

Previously script was running fine.

Any clues/help will be highly appreciable.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 182, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f163156c160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<.............>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/test_connection/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f163156c160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/pf_cic_etl_script_v2.py", line 50, in <module>
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<...............>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/test_connection/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f163156c160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
Killed
```

Process kill logs-

```html
dmesg -T| grep -E -i -B100 'killed process'
[Sat Sep 25 06:08:31 2021] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
[Sat Sep 25 06:08:31 2021] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
[Sat Sep 25 06:08:31 2021] [   1643]  1000  1643   517804   455512  4157440        0             0 python3
[Sat Sep 25 06:08:31 2021] [   1651]     0  1651     5954       69    86016        0             0 apport
[Sat Sep 25 06:08:31 2021] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice,task=python3,pid=1643,uid=1000
[Sat Sep 25 06:08:31 2021] Out of memory: Killed process 1643 (python3) total-vm:2071216kB, anon-rss:1822048kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:4060kB oom_score_adj:0
```

Comment: "Temporary failure in name resolution" Means some hostname you are trying to reach can not be resolved to an IP address and hence the connection can not happen. The resolution is typically via the DNS but can be otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, in my case it was not DNS issue.
The issue is related to the OOM(Out of memory) of the ec2 instance which is killing the process of a python script due to which the  "Instance reachability check failed" and I was getting "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution".

After upgrading ec2 instance, the instance reachability didn't fail and able to run python script containing api.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/system-reachability-check/

The instance status check failure indicates an issue with the reachability of the instance. This issue occurs due to operating system-level errors such as the following:

Failure to boot the operating system
Failure to mount the volumes correctly
Exhausted CPU and memory- This is happening in our case.
Kernel panic

Answer (score 1):

I also had such an error in my Hostinger 20 GB VPS while I was trying to run my *letsencrypt* script. The issue is directly related to the disk running out. I run the below command to remove all docker containers and claimed 17.4 GB. The issue has been resolved afterward:

```
sudo docker system prune --all
```